# Node.js circom command not found

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, circom

Using windows 11 and VS Code.

I installed circom and snarkjs:

```
npm install -g circom
```

and

```
npm install -g snarkjs
```

which seemed to install fine.

I also installed the extention:

> circom-highlighting-vscode v0.0.2

Now when I run the command:

```
circom InRange.circom -o InRange.json
```

I get the error:

> bash: circom: command not found

I also installed this path in system variables:

> C:\Users\someUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\circom\node_modules.bin

and I get a similar error with snarkjs:

```
snarkjs setup setup -c InRange.json
```

> bash: snarkjs: command not found

I figure if I can solve the first one, then the second one will be solved.

I have been troubleshooting this for hours with no success. Can someone recommend a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: has your shell picked up on the `PATH` environment variable change yet? If not, restart the shell so it can do so.

Comment: I have rebooted the pc.  That should do it, right?

Answer (score 0):

run it with sudo like `sudo npm install -g snarkjs`. it helps me